# deleting object through pointer to base without virtual destructor

Tags: c++, destructor, delete-operator, virtual-destructor

I have the code:

```
class A1 {
public:
    A1() { cout << "A1"; }
    virtual ~A1() { cout << "~A1"; }
};

class A2 {
public:
    A2() { cout << "A2"; }
    ~A2() { cout << "~A2"; }
};

class B : public A1, A2 {
public:
    B() { cout << "B"; }
    ~B() { cout << "~B"; }
};

int main() {
    A1* pa1 = new B;
    delete pa1;

    return 0;
}
```

It works totally fine because I use a virtual destructor. Output: `A1A2B~B~A2~A1` as expected.
Then I remove `virtual`:

```
class A1 {
public:
    A1() { cout << "A1"; }
    ~A1() { cout << "~A1"; }
};

class A2 {
public:
    A2() { cout << "A2"; }
    ~A2() { cout << "~A2"; }
};

class B : public A1, A2 {
public:
    B() { cout << "B"; }
    ~B() { cout << "~B"; }
};

int main() {
    A1* pa1 = new B;
    delete pa1;

    return 0;
}
```

And it outputs this: `A1A2B~A1`, which I don't understand. I thought it was supposed to output `A1A2B` since `~B()` isn't going to run, and we don't have an instance of A1, so `~A1()` should not be invoked as well. And then, why only `~A1()` is running, without `~A2()`? Why does it behave like this?

Comment: Deleting a derived class through a base class pointer when the destructor is not virtual is *undefined behaviour*. Whatever expectations you had, they were wrong.

Comment: You don't need to put "C++" in all your question titles. You've used the C++ language tag and that's sufficient.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without `virtual` the destructor is resolved statically, based on the declared type of the pointer. The compiler sees an `A1 *` so `delete pa1` will call the `~A1` destructor, and nothing else.

> we don't have an instance of A1, so ~A1() should not be invoked as well.

`B` is derived from `A1` so an instance of `A1` exists as a subobject of every `B`. Otherwise `A1* pa1 = new B;` would not even compile.

> And then, why only ~A1() is running, without ~A2()? Why does it behave like this?

Because the pointer is declared as an `A1 *`. That the actual object pointed to is a `B` does not matter since the destructor is not virtual.

The same way, if you changed the `A2` inheritance to public and declared `A2 *pa2 = new B;` then `delete pa2` would call `~A2` and nothing else.

---

[ *EDIT* ] The above attempts to answer the direct question of how the compiler resolves the destructor call. An important caveat, however, is that deleting a pointer to a derived type through the base pointer is technically UB ([undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub)) when the destructor of the base class is *not* virtual. Quoting from the C++ standard 5.3.5/3:

> *In the ﬁrst alternative (delete object), if the static type of the object to be deleted is diﬀerent from its
> dynamic type, the static type shall be a base class of the dynamic type of the object to be deleted* ***and the
> static type shall have a virtual destructor*** *or the behavior is undeﬁned*.

In practice, many implementations will allow non-virtual destructors to still "work" as expected in certain simple cases, such as single inheritance between non-polymorphic types. Might even work for pointers to the *first* base class in a multiple inheritance case (for example, the `pa1` above). But it's still UB strictly speaking, and there are cases where it's almost guaranteed to fail, such as pointers to a base class other than the first one (see an example of one such error [here](https://godbolt.org/z/jKhEqT)).

Comment: That might be what this implementation does (and many others, though not guaranteed), but it is actually full Undefined Behavior.

Comment: @Deduplicator That's correct, I added a note to that effect.